# How to change Listbox Itemdata.detail font size in run time Delphi 10.3

Tags: firemonkey, listboxitem, delphi-10.3-rio

I am working with a Listbox and I am trying to change the Font Size of the listbox "Itemdata.detail" proporty in runtime. 
I was able to change the "ItemData.Text" font size, but I need also to change the font size for the "ItemData.Detail"

{
With ListBoxItem do
            Begin
              StyledSettings:=[TStyledSetting.Family,TStyledSetting.Style,TStyledSetting.FontColor,TStyledSetting.Other];
              Size.Height:=50;
              Font.Size:=12;

```
          Size.PlatformDefault := False;
          Text :=FormPrincipal.UniqueryGeral.Fields[1].AsString;
          ItemData.Detail:= FormPrincipal.UniqueryGeral.Fields[0].AsString+' vezes '+'/'+' ACERTOS = '+FormatFloat('###.##',FormPrincipal.UniqueryGeral.Fields[2].asFloat)+'%'+' - ERROS= '+FormatFloat('###.##',(FormPrincipal.UniqueryGeral.Fields[3].AsFloat))+'%';
          StyleLookup := 'listboxitembottomdetail';
          Visible := True;
          Parent := FormPrincipal.ListBox_EstatisticasPROF_2_Resultado;
          Inc(conta_linha);
        End;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Style customization for `TListBoxItem` at design time is very limited. Try this:

```
ListBoxItem.StylesData['detail.TextSettings.Font.Size']:=20;
```

It takes advantage of the `StylesData` property which stores values for the properties of all the objects inside a style at run time. Style `listboxitembottomdetail` [is composed of a few objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usyeh.png) including one named `detail` which is a `TText` object and is mapped to the `ItemData.Detail` property of the `TListBoxItem`. Combining the name of the object and the desired property allows access to it.

If you want to change detail text font color do this instead:

```
ListBoxItem.StylesData['detail.TextSettings.FontColor']:=TAlphaColors.Blue;
```